# converting date formats with awk/gawk on macOS

Tags: awk, date, macos

I have millions of rows of data my boss has asked me to reformat for them.

The format is:

```
06/28/2022,04:00,142.01,142.38,141.59,142.15,3151
06/28/2022,04:01,142.1,142.1,142.1,142.1,196
```

I need to reformat the first date field to:

```
20220628,04:00,142.01,142.38,141.59,142.15,3151
20220628,04:01,142.1,142.1,142.1,142.1,196
```

%Y%m%d

I have the following:

```
gawk -F"," '{OFS=","; $1=strftime("%Y%m%d", $1); print $0}' AAPL.txt > AAPL.csv
```

but the weird thing is it works, but produces a date in 1969.

```
19691231,04:00,142.01,142.38,141.59,142.15,3151
19691231,04:01,142.1,142.1,142.1,142.1,196
```

I don't understand why. I chose `gawk` because `awk` on MacOS doesn't have `strftime` and calling `date` externally create a huge performance hit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code does not do what you expect it to do because the GNU `awk` `strftime()` expects a Unix timestamp as its second argument.  It's unable to parse an arbitrary datetime string.

However, we don't really need `strftime()` here.

```bash
$ awk -F , 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { split($1,a,"/"); $1 = a[3] a[1] a[2] }; 1' file
20220628,04:00,142.01,142.38,141.59,142.15,3151
20220628,04:01,142.1,142.1,142.1,142.1,196
```

This treats each line of input as simple comma-delimited fields and splits the first such field up on `/` into the array `a`.  The first field is then re-formed as the elements of the array concatenated in the wanted order.

The lone `1` at the end of the `awk` code causes the modified record to be outputted.

This would work with the default `awk` on macOS.  It does not need special date formatting functions as it treats the input date as a string and simple reorganises it.  The only assumption about the date is that it always is in the `DD/MM/YYYY` format in the input and that it should be in the `YYYYMMDD` format in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need function like `strftime` to do date-handling since all you need to do is swap fields. `sed` works nice here :

```
sed 's@\([^/]*\)/\([^/]*\)/\([^,]*\)@\3\1\2@' sample
```